# Azure Diagnostics won't create WADLogsTable

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, diagnostics, webrole

I wanted to add logging to an existing azure cloud service using NLog and Azure Diagnostics, i went through all the steps described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn482131.aspx

But, unfortunately when testing the cloud service the WADLogsTable table storage does not created, and no information gets stored here. Not on local development storage, nor on azure.

diagnostics.wadcfg:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration configurationChangePollInterval="PT1M" overallQuotaInMB="4096" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs />
  <Directories>
    <IISLogs container="wad-iis-logfiles" directoryQuotaInMB="1024" />
    <CrashDumps container="wad-crash-dumps" />
  </Directories>
  <Logs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" />
  <PerformanceCounters bufferQuotaInMB="512">
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
  </PerformanceCounters>
  <WindowsEventLog bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose">
    <DataSource name="Application!*" />
  </WindowsEventLog>
</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

ServiceConfiguration.Local.csfg (the same at Cloud, just with the correct table storage account)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="AAService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
  <Role name="Web.Services.AAService">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

ServiceDefinition.csdef

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AAService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
  <WebRole name="Web.Services.AAService" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="Web.Services.AAService.svclog" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

WebRole entrypoint

```cs
 public override bool OnStart()
        {
            // To enable the AzureLocalStorageTraceListner, uncomment relevent section in the web.config  
            DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
            diagnosticConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            diagnosticConfig.Directories.DataSources.Add(AzureLocalStorageTraceListener.GetLogDirectory());

            DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagnosticConfig);

            // For information on handling configuration changes
            // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

            return base.OnStart();
        }
```

cloud service web.config also has:

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Does anyone have any ide why is this doesnt make any trace logs? I called Trace.WriteLine() many places where the application goes through for sure, but still no WADLogsTable.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all the Diagnostic* code in OnStart.  The `<Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />` in your csdef will automatically start the diagnostics agent, and the diagnostics agent will read the settings from the .wadcfg.  Your code in OnStart is unnecessary and is overriding the wadcfg settings due to the order of precedence of loading WAD configuration.

Also note that if you are trying to update an existing cloud service then you will need to first delete the XML file in blob storage.  If a file already exists in blob storage then the diagnostics agent will ignore the .wadcfg settings.  The file you are looking for is in wad-control-container and will be named with the deployment ID and role name.